# jquery Rollover navigation breaking in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, navigation, rollover-effect

I am working on a jquery navigation. All's well in everything except IE. Functionality for the jquery rollover state does not work. Any thoughts? I have the wrapper navigation coded and there is a changeover effect on rollover for each link. I am thinking that I might be missing some sort of element as a work around in IE, but I am not sure. I've tried to look at other bits of code available and can't seem to find any help on what I'm missing on this one. Thank you!

CSS:

```
#menu {
    height: 45px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative
}

.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
    /* width and height of the menu items */
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.menu ul li a {
    /* must be postioned relative  */
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 190px;
    height: 45px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu ul li a span {
    /* all layers will be absolute positioned */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 190px;
}

.menu ul li a span.out {
    top: 0px;
}

.menu ul li a span.over, .menu ul li a span.bg {
    /* hide */
    top: -45px;
}

#menu {
    background: #000;
}

#menu ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
}

#menu ul li a span.over {
    background: #FFF;
    color: #fb8f2c;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <!--begin wrapper-->

            <div id="header">
                <!--begin header-->

                <div id="header-top">
                    <div id="left"><img src="images/LFMD_Logo_white.png" style="border: none" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="right">
                        <p>
                            (415) 655.7546
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div><!--end header top-->

                <div id="menu" class="menu">
                    <!--begin menu-->
                    <ul>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="out"> <span class="out">Link1</span> <span class="over"></span> </span><span class="bg"></span><span class="over"> </span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="out">Link2</span><span class="bg"></span><span class="over"></span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="out">Link3</span><span class="bg"></span><span class="over"></span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="out">Link4</span><span class="bg"></span><span class="over"></span></a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="out">Link5</span><span class="bg"></span><span class="over"></span></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div><!--end menu-->

            </div><!--end header-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /// wrap inner content of each anchor with first layer and append background layer
    $("#menu li a").wrapInner('<span class="out"></span>').append('<span class="bg"></span>');
    // loop each anchor and add copy of text content
    $("#menu li a").each(function() {
        $('<span class="over">' + $(this).text() + '</span>').appendTo(this);
    });
    $("#menu li a").hover(function() {
        // this function is fired when the mouse is moved over
        $(".out", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '45px'
        }, 250);
        // move down - hide
        $(".over", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '0px'
        }, 250);
        // move down - show
        $(".bg", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '0px'
        }, 120);
        // move down - show
    }, function() {
        // this function is fired when the mouse is moved off
        $(".out", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '0px'
        }, 250);
        // move up - show
        $(".over", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '-45px'
        }, 250);
        // move up - hide
        $(".bg", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '-45px'
        }, 120);
        // move up - hide
    });

    $("#menu2 li a").wrapInner('<span class="out"></span>');
    $("#menu2 li a").each(function() {
        $('<span class="over">' + $(this).text() + '</span>').appendTo(this);
    });
    $("#menu2 li a").hover(function() {
        $(".out", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '45px'
        }, 200);
        // move down - hide
        $(".over", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '0px'
        }, 200);
        // move down - show
    }, function() {
        $(".out", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '0px'
        }, 200);
        // move up - show
        $(".over", this).stop().animate({
            'top' : '-45px'
        }, 200);
        // move up - hide
    });
});
```

Comment: Works for me in IE10. If anyone is interested in looking into it with more ease, here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLBfb/).

Comment: Works in IE10 and IE9, IE8, IE7 mode. Full JSFiddle site itself doesn't work in IE8 mode so I used full-screen preview of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLBfb/embedded/result/

Comment: You can try to use newer version of jQuery library. Please try to use 1.9 instead of 1.3. Do not use jQuery 2.0 because it doesn't support old IE browsers.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. Looks like it was related to a combination of the version I was running and the older library on my side. Thanks a bunch.